# How to show the data from an array list in HTA

Tags: vbscript, hta

I have a [VBScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript) script that I am using to check if a group of software are install in a computer if they are installed i just wanted to display in the [HTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application).

But I am having a problem display that information in HTA. How do I fix it?

Here is the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Uninstall</title>
        <HTA:APPLICATION
            APPLICATIONNAME="Script Command Center"
            ID="oInstall"
            VERSION="1.0"
            SCROLL = "yes"
            Icon=""
            SINGLEINSTANCE="no"
            WINDOWSTATE="fixed"
        />
    </head>

    <SCRIPT Language = "VBScript">
        Const adVarChar = 200
        Const MaxCharacters = 255
        Set DataList = CreateObject("ADOR.Recordset")

        Sub Subroutine1
            DataArea.InnerHTML = "Searching ...... please wait"
            document.body.style.cursor = "wait"
            idTimer = window.setTimeout("Subroutine2", 2000, "VBScript")
        End Sub

        Sub Subroutine2
            window.clearTimeout(idTimer)
            On Error Resume Next
            Dim strAnswere
            Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
            Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
            AppList = Array("Torrent","Toshiba", "Java")
            For Each AppName in AppList
                'WSCript.Echo "Searching for keyword: " & AppName
                'First, find the GUID
                strComputer = "."
                Set objReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
                strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
                objReg.EnumKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, arrSubKeys,strName

                For Each subkey In arrSubKeys
                    InstalledAppName = ""
                    InstalledAppName = WshShell.RegRead("HKLM\" & strKeyPath & "\" & subkey & "\DisplayName")
                    InstalledAppVersion = WshShell.RegRead("HKLM\" & strKeyPath & "\" & subkey & "\DisplayVersion")
                    'Wscript.Echo InstalledAppName
                    If InStr(1,InstalledAppName,AppName,1) > 0 Then
                        strName = InstalledAppName
                        DataList("SoftwareName") = strName

                        RawGUID = ""
                        GUID = ""
                        RawGUID = WshShell.RegRead("HKLM\" & strKeyPath & "\" & subkey & "\UninstallString")
                        GUID = Mid(RawGUID, instr(RawGUID, "{"), 38)
                        'WSCript.Echo GUID
                        If GUID<>"" Then
                            strAnswere = MsgBox("Do you want to Uninstall " & AppName & " Version " & InstalledAppVersion &" ? ", vbYesNoCancel, "Uninstaller")
                            If strAnswere = vbYes Then
                                WshShell.Run "msiexec /x " & GUID & " /q"
                            ElseIf strAnswere = vbCancel Then
                                Wscript.Echo "Cancel was clicked... Quitting."
                                Wscript.Quit
                            ElseIf strAnswere = vbNo Then
                                WScript.Echo "The App still install"
                                DataArea.InnerHTML = strHTML
                                DataList("SoftwareName") = strName
                                DataList.Fields.Append "SoftwareName", adVarChar, MaxCharacters
                                DataList.Fields.Append "Vendor", adVarChar, MaxCharacters
                                DataList.Fields.Append "Version", adVarChar, MaxCharacters
                                DataList.Fields.Append "UninstallString", adVarChar, MaxCharacters
                                DataList.Open

                                strHTML = "<form name=""softwareform"" method=""post"">" & _
                                          "<table class=""softwaretable"">" & _
                                          "<tr>" & _
                                              "<th style=""width:30%;text-align:left;cursor:hand;"" " & _
                                                  "title=""Sort by Software Title"" onClick=SortSoftwareItems(1)>" & _
                                                  "Software Title&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;^</th>" & _
                                              "<th style=""width:24%;text-align:left;cursor:hand;"" " & _
                                                  "title=""Sort by Vendor"" onClick=SortSoftwareItems(2)>Vendor</th>" & _
                                              "<th style=""width:15%;text-align:left;cursor:hand;"" " & _
                                                  "title=""Sort by Version"" onClick=SortSoftwareItems(3)>Version</th>" & _
                                              "<th style=""width:8%;"">&nbsp;</th>" & _
                                              "<th style=""width:8%;"">&nbsp;</th>" & _
                                          "</tr>"
                            End If
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
                If subkey = "" Then
                    WScript.Echo "no"
                End If
            Next
        End Sub
    </SCRIPT>

    <body>
        <h1 style="text-align:center">uninstall</h1>
        <input type="button" value="Count Events" onClick="Subroutine1"><p>

        <span id=SoftwareNameArea></span>
        <span id=SoftwareVersionArea></span>
        <br /><br />

        <div id="DataArea"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what the problem is exactly. There are two common ways to manipulate your HTA document: 1. write HTML to the document, with an array is would be something like `strHTML = "<tr><td>" & join(rowArray,"</td><td>") & </td></tr>"` or 2. use [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) manipulation to append objects and data to the document. The latter is more difficult, but is providing more flexibility and extensibility. With VBScript, you can access the same set of methods as you can with [javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp).

Comment: thank you for answer the problem that i am having is that i haven't figure how to append the name of the array list to the table

Comment: Cleaned the code a bit so we can see what is happening. You are doing four things in the main loop: Getting the app name, retrieving the GUID, asking for uninstall and if the users answers no, you write the header of the softwaretable. When you split these four actions into separate functions it is easier to see where it goes wrong. You are doing some strange things with strHTML and also the creation of the table is on a strange place. Better put the innerHtml into your strHTML and then append additional rows onto strHTML. At last, update the innerHtml to strHTML.

Comment: The sample HTML is not *[well-formed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_element)* - the SCRIPT tag is not inside html or body tags.